# How to get width without inheriting its parent?

Tags: css

Suppose, this html and css...

```
<div>
  <div>test</div>
</div>

div{width: 80%;}
```

The test div will get 80% of 80% i.e. 64% width because it's inheriting from its parent div. Obviously if it was set with em like 80em then it will also inherit and get 64%. But instead of using em, there is rem which works perfectly without inheriting it's parent.

So, Is there any replacement for percentage like em to rem?

Comment: Might not be well-suite depending on your case, but making the divs ```position:fixed``` will do it.

Comment: Are you stuck without the ability to give them classes?

Comment: What if you give classes to both but assign width 80% ? I'm just willing to know for replacement

Comment: Sorry, I guess I don't understand. I've never styled a div without a class.

Comment: I don't think there is anyway to reference the window width instead of the parent element. It's 80% of it's parent.

Comment: Though I've never used it personally, there is [**Viewport-percentage measurement**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#vw-unit).

Comment: @Frankenscarf that's cool. I think you should answer. But be care that inherits or not?

Comment: Well, I feel it's unclear what you are trying to achieve without seeing the problem in context, so while it may answer the "is there any alternative" question, it doesn't really fit the code model you supplied. PLUS, I'm hesitant to recommend anything I haven't ever played with.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't any replacement. Depending on what you're trying to achieve, the following may be what you're looking for:

```
div{width:80%;}
div > div{width:100%;}
```

Comment: I wanted to know just with keeping 80%. But you said it's not available. Anyway Thank you.

Comment: care should be taken with this approach as a third level of div will also have this subclass apply to it (because it matches the pattern). `<div><div><div>level 3</div></div></div>` if you don't want this to be the case then maybe start at the body level - i.e. `body > div > div { width:100% }

Answer (score 0):

What you are lookin for (I guess) is vw (viewport width)

```
div { 
    width: 80vw;
}
```

makes the div 80% of the viewport (that is, the browser window - more or less)

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W6hQj/)